# I'm trying to create a ggplot, but this message occurs "Data must be a data frame" how to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: I used tibble function created an dataframe. And it does printed out the table.]

[image: And then I'm trying to use the ggplot to create a geom_line graph. But it does not work out.]

I got these error message, how do I fix it?

Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.
Backtrace:

1. ggplot2::ggplot(data = covid_sim, )
2. ggplot2:::ggplot.default(data = covid_sim, )
3. ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
   Error in fortify(data, ...) :

[image: I tried pull it out from the ggplot()+, then I still getting this error message]

Comment: Your data is now a `vector`. You should use a `data frame`.

Comment: Your object `covid_sim` seems to be a vector. In the first chunk that you show, it should be be `covid_sim <- tibble(days_range, ... ` and not `covid_sim <- c(days_range, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard reproducing your problem without the data and code but I tried. The problem is that your data `covid_sim` is currently a `vector` which should be a `dataframe`. If you run the following code, it should work:

```
covid_sim <- data.frame(susceptible = susceptible, 
                        infectious = infectious, 
                        recovered = recovered,
                        days_range = days_range)

library(tidyverse)

covid_sim %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = days_range, y = susceptible, color = "susceptible")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = days_range, y = infectious, color = "infectious")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = days_range, y = recoverd, color = "recovered")) +
  labs(title = "Simulated COVID-19 cases from SIR model",
       x = "Days in USA",
       y = "Number of People")
```